# Cannot set the position of a game object after detaching it from parent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want the player to be able to drop the gun and pick up a new one but I can seem to reposition the gun. The current gun is a child of the player and its position is set relative to the player but when I use

transform.parent = null;

it sets the position of the gun in world space and I can change the position by creating a new vector fr the position.

When the player drops the gun, I want it to set its position where the player is and detach it from the player and then I guess I can use rigidbody to apply physics to it and drop it on the floor.

Comment: You say you can't set the position, yet then you say you can. Which is it? What's the problem? What are you asking?

Comment: I meant to say "Cant" I missed the T. The local position of the gun gets set as the world position and I cannot change this position.

Comment: So why can't you change the gun's `transform.position` to what you want? It's a world position, sure, but it's still changeable.